Issue with config template in BOSH release
I need some help with my first Bosh release, please? I am learning Bosh currently. Following is the spec file inside a job called 'rubyweb':
---
name: rubyweb

templates:
  ctl.erb: bin/ctl
  config.erb: cfg/config.yml

packages:
- ruby-2.7

properties:
  port:
    description: "Specify the port for the Web-app to listen on"
    default: 8080
  bootstrap:
    description: "Specify the main file used to run the app"
    default: "app.rb"

Following is the config.erb file:
port: <%=
port = p('port')

if (!port.eql? 8080) || (!port.eql? 8081)
  raise "Invalid port number"
end
port
%>

Following is the test case that is failing:
let(:conf_template) {job.template('cfg/config.yml')}

it 'raises error if configs are wrong' do
  expect {conf_template.render('port' => 1024)}.to raise_error 'Invalid port number'
  expect {conf_template.render('port' => 7999)}.to raise_error 'Invalid port number'
  expect {conf_template.render('port' => 8080)}.not_to raise_error 
end

it 'raises error if yml is not parsable or malformed' do 
  parsable = true
  begin
    yml = YAML.load(conf_template.render('port' => 8080))
  rescue StandardError => e
    parsable = false
  end
    expect(parsable).to be true
    expect(yml['port']).to eq(8080)
end

Following is the error when the test is ran:
Failures:

  1) ruby app main job: config template raises error if configs are wrong
     Failure/Error: expect {conf_template.render('port' => 1024)}.to raise_error 'Invalid port number'

       expected Exception with "Invalid port number", got #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)> with backtrace:
         # /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bosh-template-2.3.0/lib/bosh/template/test/template.rb:14:in `render'
         # ./spec/job_spec.rb:86:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/job_spec.rb:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/job_spec.rb:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ruby app main job: config template raises error if yml is not parsable or malformed
     Failure/Error: expect(parsable).to be true

       expected true
            got false
     # ./spec/job_spec.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

